# How do I compress a Json result from ASP.NET MVC with IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, iis-7, http-compression

I'm having difficulty making IIS 7 correctly compress a Json result from ASP.NET MVC. I've enabled static and dynamic compression in IIS. I can verify with Fiddler that normal text/html and similar records are compressed. Viewing the request, the accept-encoding gzip header is present. The response has the mimetype "application/json", but is not compressed.

I've identified that the issue appears to relate to the MimeType. When I include `mimeType="*/*"`, I can see that the response is correctly gzipped. How can I get IIS to compress WITHOUT using a wildcard mimeType? I assume that this issue has something to do with the way that ASP.NET MVC generates content type headers.

The CPU usage is well below the dynamic throttling threshold. When I examine the trace logs from IIS, I can see that it fails to compress due to not finding a matching mime type.

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" noCompressionForProxies="false">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
    <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

Comment: I cannot use a wildcard mimetype since I'm encountering a strange issue with IE8 - it appears to have difficulty downloading a .zip file when the request is further gzipped by IIS. Firefox 3.5 is unaffected.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Make sure your **%WinDir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config** contains these:

```
<system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />       
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
</system.webServer>
```

From the [link](http://forums.iis.net/p/1155809/1895877.aspx) of @AtanasKorchev.

As @simon_weaver said in the comments, you might be editing the wrong file with a 32 bit editor on a 64 bit Windows, use notepad.exe to make sure this file is indeed modified.

Comment: NTOE: if `applicationHost.config` appears to me missing you're probably on a 64 bit machine using a 32 bit editor. Try notepad AFTER MAKING BACKUP of course. http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Aug/09/Editing-Applicationhostconfig-on-64-bit-Win2008

Comment: Hours, hours I tell you, I've spent HOURS trying to discover why my gzipped application/json was not coming out of my IIS... This finally worked! Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to do a Recycle to the Application Pool

Answer (score 22):

I have successfully used the approach highlighted [here](http://forums.iis.net/p/1155809/1895877.aspx).

Comment: I'd seen that article before, but dismissed it as not adding anything new or useful.

Well, it appears that unlike other mime types, you need to specify the content encoding for IIS 7 to compress application/json responses from ASP.NET MVC. Saying `application/json` isn't enough; it needs to be `application/json; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: NTOE: if `applicationHost.config` appears to me missing you're probably on a 64 bit machine using a 32 bit editor. Try notepad AFTER MAKING BACKUP of course. http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Aug/09/Editing-Applicationhostconfig-on-64-bit-Win2008

Answer (score 14):

[Use this guide](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCFDataFeedsODataAndOtherCustomServicesInIIS7.aspx)

None of these answers worked for me. I did take note of the **application/json; charset=utf-8** mime-type though.

Comment: +1: this worked for me, using the `application/json; charset=utf-8` mime-type  :o)

Comment: this works for me plus you need to remember to restart the SERVER not just the website. ie after starting `inetmgr` click on your server name and head right to the `Manage Server` section - use that restart and not the individual website restart

Answer (score 7):

I recommend [this approach](https://web.archive.org/web/20150527040730/http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/asp-net-mvc-action-filter-caching-and-compression)
Create `CompressAttribute` class, and set target action.

Comment: Only when everything else fails? shouldn't IIS7+ do a better job?

Comment: This is a nice solution because you can cache and compress whereas IIS will only cache or compress

Comment: This is also a nice approach in that compressing small messages can cost more in compress/decompress that they would have in vanilla transmission of the data.  Setting gzip for all JSON downloads in an application can actually cost time for these smaller messages, so decorating only large(r) downloads has its advantages.

Comment: Updated link to archive.org

Answer (score 2):

The ActionFilterAttribute approach updated for ASP.NET 4.x and Includes Brotli.NET package.

```
using System;
using System.IO.Compression;
using Brotli;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;


public class CompressFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding)) return;

        acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();
        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (acceptEncoding.Contains("BR"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "br");
            response.Filter = new BrotliStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
        else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
            response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
        else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
    }
}
```